# Package modifier produces error

Tags: java, package, access-modifiers

Eclipse is giving me an error when defining a top level class with the package modifier, the error is :

```
syntax error on token "package", delete this token.
```

My code is simpy:

```
package class MyClass { ... }
```

My google-foo seems to be broken, any help would be great! Please ask any questions necessary...

Thanks!

Comment: There are only 4 access modifiers in Java: Private, public, protected and default. There is no modifier by the name of package. Hence the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to delcare a class as package private, you should omit the modifier.  The `package` keyword is used to define packages.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. It's simply not valid Java - because package *isn't* a modifier.

You declare a package with the `package` keyword; you declare a class with the `class` keyword:

```
package foo;

class Bar
{
}
```

If you're trying to explicitly specify the default "package level" accessibility, that (unfortunately IMO) can't be specified explicitly. Just leave all access modifiers off.